# Summing binomial coefficients and manipulating summation order

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm having trouble understanding Example 3 (pg. 61).

As a preliminary, the solution makes use of the following two identities, which I've restated below for convenience:

1. Eq. (25) on pg. 59:

   $$\sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{r-k}{m}\binom{s+k}{n} = \binom{r+s+1}{m+n+1}, \\ \{n,s,m,r\} \in \mathbb{Z}, \ n ≥ s ≥ 0, \ m ≥ 0, \ r ≥ 0. \tag{25}$$
2. Eq. (28) on pg. 61:

   $$\sum_{k} \binom{n+k}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} = \delta_{n0},
   \ integer \ n ≥ 0. \tag{28}$$

---

Example 3 (pg. 61) asks the following:

> **Example 3.** What is the value of $\sum_{k} \binom{n+k}{m+2k}\binom{2k}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$, for positive integers $m$ and $n$?

The author starts off by using Eq. (25) above to replace the $\binom{n+k}{m+2k}$ term by a sum of terms of the form $\binom{x+k}{2k}$:

> Accordingly, we use Eq. (25) with
>
> $$r = n + k − 1, m = 2k, s = 0, n = m − 1,$$
>
> and we have
>
> $$\sum_{k}\sum_{0 \le j \le n+k-1} \binom{n+k-1-j}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{j}{m-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}. \tag{29}$$

The solution continues on pg. 62:

> We wish to perform the summation on $k$ first; but interchanging the order of summation demands that we sum on the values of $k$ that are $≥ 0$ and $≥ j−n+1$. **Unfortunately, the latter condition raises problems, because we do not know the desired sum if $j ≥ n$. Let us save the situation, however, by observing the terms of (29) are zero when $n ≤ j ≤ n+k −1$.** This condition implies that $k ≥ 1$; **thus $0 ≤ n + k − 1 − j ≤ k − 1 < 2k$, and the first binomial coefficient in (29) will vanish. We may therefore replace the condition on the second sum by $0 ≤ j < n$,** and the interchange of summation is routine. Summing on $k$ by Eq. (28) now gives
>
> $$\sum_{0 \le j < n}\binom{j}{m-1}\delta_{(n-1-j)0},$$
>
> and all terms are zero except when $j = n − 1$. Hence our final answer is
>
> $$\binom{n-1}{m-1}.$$

**Questions:** *I'm struggling to understand the text in bold.*

- Why don't we know the value of the sum if $j \geq n$?
- How are the terms of Eq. (29) zero when $n \le j \le n+k−1$ - doesn't that condition only make sense when $k \geq 1$?
- How does $k \geq 1$ imply $0 ≤ n + k − 1 − j ≤ k − 1 < 2k$? I get that we can rearrange $k \geq 1$ as $0 \leq k-1$, but how do we know that $n + k − 1 − j ≤ k − 1$?

Comment: (1) See constraints of variable in eq 25 where we had $n \ge s \ge 0$.   (2) If $n \le j \le n + k-1$, we have $\binom{n + k - 1 - j}{2k} = 0$ since we are trying to choose more objects from fewer objects. (3) since $j \le n$, $n + k - 1 - j = k - 1 - (n-j) \le k-1$

Comment: Thanks so much @sku! Your explanation for (3) really helps with understanding (3) and (2), but do you mean "since $j \geq n$"? That would explain the minus sign before $(n-j)$ in your comment, since if $j \geq n$, then $0 \geq n-j$ meaning $n-j$ is a negative number.

Comment: I’m still unsure about (1). Eq. 25 holds for $n \geq s \geq 0$, which is $m-1 \geq 0$ in our context (since we set $n = m-1$ and $s = 0$ to get Eq. (29)) – but how does this relate to $j \geq n$. The $j$ in Eq. (29) is the $k$ in Eq. (25), but Eq. (25) does not place any constraints on $k$.

Comment: On (1), we are interchanging summations: $0 \le k \le n$ and $0 \le j \le n-k+1$. When we do this, we will get summations over $0 \le j \le 2n-1$ and $0 \le k \le j - n +1$ The inner sum also has condition of $k \ge 0$. Now what happens for when outer sum's $j$ is in $n \le j \le 2n-1$. This will produce the inner sums lower index to go from $k = 1, 2, .... etc$. But we want the inner sum also to go from $k = 0$.. This is a wrinkle. But luckily, for all $j$ in $n \le j \le 2n-1$, the sum goes to zero leaving us with the sums with indices in the right form.

Comment: Thank you @sku! I think I was confused by the wording in this bit in the book: "interchanging the order of summation demands that we sum on the values of $k$ that are $≥ 0$ and $≥ j−n+1$. Unfortunately, the latter condition raises problems, because we do not know the desired sum if $j ≥ n$." - I didn't understand why we had to consider $j \geq n$. But your explanation helps there because you show that $j$ can go up to $2n-1$, so we have to consider the range $n \leq j \leq 2n-1$.

Comment: Also, if you wish to post your explanation as a solution, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: one correction to my last comment starting with "when we do this", we will get summations over $0 \le j \le 2n-1$ and lower limit of ($k \ge 0$ or $k \ge j-n+1)$ whichever is greater and upper limit of $k \le n$.

Comment: By "whichever is greater", do you mean whichever lower limit of $k$ is greater? I tried using Iverson's brackets to do the interchange but couldn't work out the interval for $k$. I'm terrible at manipulating inequalitites :(

Comment: yes. whichever lower limit is greater. So when $j \ge n$, we get entire sum as $0$ and when $j \le n-1$, we get lower limit as max($k \ge 0$, ($k \ge $ negative number or $0$)).